# Get all lists which contains a subset of items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a *News* object that contains a property called *tags*, which is a list of strings.

From a collection of this object, I would like to obtain those *News* items that contains a subset of strings (for example: tag1, tag3, tag5) in it's property *tags*. But all of them, not just one. How could I do it with LINQ? (if possible)?

Comment: Does `.Select()` not work for you? Show us some code, and what you have tried so far...

Comment: It sounds like you have an XML RSS feed.  Best way is to use XDocument/XElement (xml linq) to get elements.  Need to see the xml format to give more specific answer.  You can make a list of tags and then check using Contains() method.  The Element names can be gotten using x.Name.LocalName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.All` + `Contains`:

```
var tags = new List<string>{"tag1", "tag3", "tag5"};
var query = allNews.Where(n => tags.All(n.Tags.Contains));
```

or `!tags.Except(n.Tags).Any`:

```
var query = allNews.Where(n => !tags.Except(n.Tags).Any());
```

or (my favorite if you can change the collection type) use [`HashSet.IsSubsetOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var tags = new HashSet<string> { "tag1", "tag3", "tag5" };
var query = allNews.Where(n => tags.IsSubsetOf(n.Tags));
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks everyone for your help (and sorry for forget to put an example in my question)

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
list.Where(x => new[] {"tag1", "tag3", "tag5"}.All(y => x.Tags.Contains(y)));
```

It filters out the `News` objects whose `Tags` property is not a superset of {"tag1", "tag3", "tag5"}.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

`List<News> sample = collection.Where(x => x.tags.Intersect(tags).Count() > 0).ToList();`

Explanation:

I created a sample application for your case see if it helps

```
    List<News> collection = new List<News>();
    collection.Add(new News());
    collection.Add(new News());
    collection.Add(new News());
    collection.Add(new News());

    List<string> tags = new List<string>();
    tags.Add("tag1");
    tags.Add("tag2");
    tags.Add("tag3");

    collection[0].tags = tags;
    collection[0].tags.AddRange(tags);
    collection[1].tags = new List<string>();
    collection[2].tags = new List<string>();
    collection[3].tags = new List<string>();

    List<News> sample = collection.Where(x => x.tags.Intersect(tags).Count() > 0).ToList();
```

Result Screenshot

[image]